# How to get the BSSID of currently connected network through bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a small script that needs the BSSID of the wireless network that my computer is currently connected to and store it in a variable.
I'm sorry if my question is weird -- I am VERY new to bash -- but I was wondering if such a thing was possible?
Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please see [ask], right now your Question is too broad, I guess! Get startet trying and tell us where you got stuck by providing a [mcve]!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

In 2022 the answer via iw tool is

`iw dev <device> link`

My current state while connected to `SomeWiFi` with BSSID `18:e8:29:6e:e1:4a`:

```
root@sdr-lt:~# iw dev wlp0s20f3 link 
Connected to 18:e8:29:6e:e1:4a (on wlp0s20f3)
SSID: SomeWiFi
freq: 5220
RX: 82053829 bytes (116477 packets)
TX: 23572821 bytes (41359 packets)
signal: -53 dBm
rx bitrate: 400.0 MBit/s VHT-MCS 9 40MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2
tx bitrate: 400.0 MBit/s VHT-MCS 9 40MHz short GI VHT-NSS 2

bss flags:      short-slot-time
dtim period:    3
beacon int:     100
root@sdr-lt:~#
```

Answer (score 2):

the utility `iwconfig` will show the BSSID as "Access Point", in the second row of the interface report. For example in my system:

```
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"My WIFI"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 12:34:56:78:9A:BC
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=31/70  Signal level=-79 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:719  Invalid misc:1972   Missed beacon:0
```

you can filter it out, with

```
iwconfig wlp2s0 | sed -n 's/.*Access Point: \([0-9\:A-F]\{17\}\).*/\1/p'
```

Obviously replacing `wlp2s0` with your interface name if it differs. If you want to save it into a variable, just put all the line inside `$()` and assign it to the variable you want:

```
BSSID=$(iwconfig wlp2s0 | sed -n 's/.*Access Point: \([0-9\:A-F]\{17\}\).*/\1/p')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the ESSID of the access point this:

```
iwconfig 2>/dev/null |grep ESSID |cut -d: -f2
```

does the job. This could be useful to get the BSSID by other means.

A way to get the BSSID involves other steps. Firstly:

```
a=$(route -n |grep ^0.0.0.0)
```

gets the default route; in my case result is "0.0.0.0  192.168.1.1 ...". Then

```
gw=$(echo $a |cut -d" " -f2)
```

gets the gateway 192.168.1.1. Then using arp we can get the hardware address:

```
rout=$(arp -a |grep $gw)
```

returns the record about the gateway, "192.168.1.1 0x1 0x2 58:98:35:..." in my case. To extract the hardware address:

```
hwadr=$(echo $rout |cut -d" " -f4)
```

I am not sure if the steps above are always correct, on any situation, but I didn't find any other way. Hope it helps.

Comment: While this works for most home appliances, the hardware address of the router might be different from the access point, in case, for example, the access point acts as a bridge).

Answer (score 0):

For DD-WRT:

wl -i eth1 status | grep 'BSSID' | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'